# Can't import Firebase Firestore into Vuejs webpack project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the new **Firestore DB** into a brand new project with **Vuejs**, but I have errors with webpack.

I'm starting the project from scratch, with `vue init webpack`. However, although I can import and use the DB in [a plain nodejs script](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/kabook/blob/firestore-raw/src/main.js) (keyfile.json is not commited for security), I can't make it work in the Vuejs project.

### Steps to reproduce (commited to Github for easy access)

1. Initialize a new project with `vue init webpack`
2. Copied the [Firestore initializer](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/kabook/blob/master/src/firebase.js)
3. Imported it into [`main.js`](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/kabook/blob/master/src/main.js#L4)
4. Tried to reconfigure [webpack](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/kabook/blob/master/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L12), but errors appear (described in detail [here](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/kabook/issues/1))

Then I have errors in console, with the main page not rendering. I've tried to reconfigure webpack in two ways, but no success… :(

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to make Firestore work in a webpack Vuejs project?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-firestore-beta? It says it's only for nodejs.

Comment: Yes, @EricGuan it's the one I'm trying to use. I thought I could use this as it's Javascript… Should I change to the [“web” version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)?

Comment: Yes. You should use the web version.

Comment: Firebase has an npm module, you can just use that.