# Firestore is not a function in a SimulatedGREG/electron-vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, google-cloud-firestore

I've been battling a tiresome error in my vue-electron application, since I began switching from [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) to [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/).

Oh yeah I know there is plenty of questions related to this console log error `Uncaught TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629683/cant-import-firebase-firestore-into-vuejs-webpack-project), [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/182), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636255/firebase-firestore-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-initialize-cloud-firestore), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877126/firestore-is-not-a-function-in-vue-cli-application?rq=1). However, I think they were in some ways all related to the missing `import 'firebase/firestore';` part.

I think my issue comes from the vue-cli template I use (`https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/vue-electron`) as, when building a VueJs app with the webpack template, I perfectly manage to implement the firestore SDK.

I add many details about my issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/464 and created a dedicated Git at https://github.com/mlapeyre3/firestore-issue-464

[image: Console error]

Has anyone here already faced this issue and can provide his help? :)

Thanks !